# SQL: Finding a value in Table

Tags: sql, select

My DataBase Table look like:

```
 ID  | key | val_string | val_integer | val_timestamp
 ----------------------------------------------------
  1  |Name | name1      | NULL        | NULL
  1  |Age  | NULL       | 10          | NULL
  1  |DOB  | NULL       | NULL        | 11-06-2004 11:33:00
  2  |Name | name2      | NULL        | NULL
  2  |Age  | NULL       | 20          | NULL
  2  |DOB  | NULL       | NULL        | 10-06-1994 10:38:00
```

Now, my application takes input from the user and returns the `ID` matching to it.

For Example, if the user input is 10, then I should be able to find ID 1. Similarly if the user input is name2, I should be able to find ID 2.

The problem over here is, all the value field is of different data type ie. val_string is of string type, `val_integer` is of integer type and so on. But, we don't know the type for user input.

Comment: Convert the fields to string and the input to string using cast.

Comment: @Jens: Don't you think that it will be less performant.

Comment: How should user enter the date? In this special database format?

Comment: @brummfondel: The User always enters String. We need to do exact match of User Input and Value in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cast to convert your data types to string  here is some links on CAST

http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-cast.html

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

hope this helps

if not let me know and il see if i can find another solution

Comment: il delete this answer as its not needed really a comment would do  but i do agree with Jens just posting it here il remove it after awhile

Comment: i honestly dont think so @Abhinav even if it does it wont impact it to a point where you will notice it  the thing is  when you get implicit conversions, or you have to put in explicit conversions, you’re performing a function on your columns that might have a small impact but in your case i dont think you will notice it

Comment: to be blunt it will get the job done with very little impact on performance and you are not  required to change your table

Answer (score 1):

You may add another varchar column "searchstring" that contains the data as string. Maybe a view is a better solution if the string is exactly the same as the data.

```
create view foo as select id,val_string from mytable where val_string is not null 
union select id,cast(val_integer as varchar) from mytable where val_integer is not null 
union select id,cast(val_timestamp as varchar) from mytable where val_timestamp is not null;
```

Comment: I can't change table structure. Possibly a view can do, but then cast in query can also be done.

Comment: But with a view you can use a single column, so no "or" operation is required: See my modified answer.